# Novice and looking for guide

Tags: wallet

please I'm new to so many things here, but these are my questions. what is really required from 
blockchain wallet in order to successfully link it
with a miner, Is it ID or Address añd how do i know for sure that it has been connected successfully

Comment: This question is far too broad and unclear for stack exchange. There are a lot of getting started guide available that can walk you through setting up a wallet and purchasing BTC, which Google can lead you to.

Answer (score 2):

> what is really required from blockchain wallet in order to successfully link it with a miner, Is it ID or Address añd how do i know for sure that it has been connected successfully

**That is not how mining works, it sounds as if you are involved in a common scam**

The scammer is probably asking for your login info, so that they can *”set your account up for mining”*. Note that mining does
NOT work this way. The scammer simply wants to log in and copy down your seed phrase. With that piece of info, even if you change your password, the scammer will be able to easily steal all bitcoin in your wallet.

DO NOT SHARE YOUR WALLET ID, PASSWORD, SEED PHRASE, PRIVATE KEYS, etc.

There is NEVER any need to do so. Anyone asking for that info is probably trying to scam you.